# Extracting elements from vector/matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Is there an operator or function in Eigen to read the elements of a vector or matrix into separate variables? For example I imagine the converse of the comma-initializer:

```
Eigen::Vector5d v;
v << a, b, c, d, e;
// ... do something with v ...
v >> a, b, c, d, e; // is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here, in one simple line?
```

The only way I know of is a 5-liner:

```
a = v(0);
b = v(1);
c = v(2);
d = v(3);
e = v(4);
```

Comment: There is a pending PR to add structured bindings to Eigen: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-requests/541/add-structured-bindings-support/